# How to position input type radio and checkbox inline position?

Tags: css, html

I want to position my radio buttons and `checkboxes` inline position I've used this `css` code but it didn't work

**css**

```
.checkbox-inline, .radio-inline {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
input[type=radio] {
     margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

html

```
<div>
 <label> <b>carburant: </b><span>(*)</span></label>
  <label class ='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='carburant' value=1 checked> AA</label>
<label><input class ='radio-inline' type='radio' name='carburant' value=2> BB</label>
<label><input class ='radio-inline' type='radio' name='carburant' value=3> CC</label>
<label><input class ='radio-inline' type='radio' name='carburant' value=4> DD</label>
</div><br />




<div>
     <label> <b>city: </b><span>(*)</span></label>
      <label class ='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='carburant' value=1 checked> AA</label>
    <label><input class ='checkbox-inline' type='checkbox' name='carburant' value=2> BB</label>
    <label><input class ='checkbox-inline' type='checkbox' name='carburant' value=3> CC</label>
    <label><input class ='checkbox-inline' type='checkbox' name='carburant' value=4> DD</label>
    </div><br />
```

I am not using twitter bootstrap ,I am working with  html5.
I want to display my  buttons on the same line.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by inline position? you want the radio next to the label text?

Comment: where are the checkboxes ?

Comment: what "didn't work"?  can you describe your problem a bit better please.  Also radio buttons are inline by default.  Why do you add 20px left padding then margin left -20px and the first class is on the label whereas the rest of them are on the input - which one do you mean to add the class to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question not very clear, but I think you want inline your radio button, I hope below solution will helps you.

```css
.checkbox-inline, .radio-inline {
    cursor: pointer;   
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div >
 <label> <b>carburant: </b><span>(*)</span></label>
  <label class ='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='carburant' value=1 checked> AA</label>
<label><input class ='radio-inline' type='radio' name='carburant' value=2> BB</label>
<label><input class ='radio-inline' type='radio' name='carburant' value=3> CC</label>
<label><input class ='radio-inline' type='radio' name='carburant' value=4> DD</label>
</div><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises from **CSS** properties assigned to `input[type=radio]` tag, remove them all, and have your check boxes sitting properly next to each other... here's the link;

[Radio Inlins](https://jsfiddle.net/2f5tw7zf/)